# How Do I Upload Data to AWS CloudSearch from .NET?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I can do a POST request from some http provider, POSTMAN, CURL, whatever to upload data to AWS Cloud Search like this:

`myawsdomain.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2017-01-01/documents/batch`

(with JSON body included)

How do I do this from the latest [.NET SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html)? I can do searches, but I am having trouble writing data to AWS CloudSearch.

Note, I don't need help parsing/creating JSON in .NET - I can do that, just the commands to write to AWS. I can't find any other info besides the docs.

Answer (score 1):

This code successfully writes to the Cloud Search Domain:

```
using Amazon.CloudSearchDomain;
using Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.Model;


        var domainConfig = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainConfig;
        {
            ServiceURL = "http://myawsdomain.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com"
        };

        var cloudSearch = new Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient(domainConfig);

        var path = @"C:\Code\myjsonfile.txt";

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream jsonFileToUpload = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        var upload = new Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.Model.UploadDocumentsRequest()
        {
            ContentType = ContentType.ApplicationJson,
            Documents = jsonFileToUpload
        };

        var response = cloudSearch.UploadDocuments(upload);
```

Comment: Is the service url obtained from describe domain function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the AWS .NET SDK has what you're looking for but this library might encapsulate the functionality you need:

https://github.com/martin-magakian/Amazing-Cloud-Search

It makes use of generics and is strongly typed - so it should be clean and fit nicely with your data model.

Comment: The SDK does have the functionality I needed, thanks for the reply though!